# AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA MacOS

Tags: macos, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu

I cloned a git repo and I'm trying to run the code. However, I realised that some operations were loaded to the GPU. The issue is that MacOS doesnt support NVIDA so I keep getting assertion error when I run the code(as seen below). Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Note that the code is quite bulky so I can't go through every file and offload these operations. Below is a sample code.

```
for batch_idx, data in enumerate(valid_generator):
    x, y, x1, y1 = data[0].squeeze(-1).to(device), data[1].squeeze(-1).to(device), data[2].squeeze(-1).to(device), data[3].squeeze(-1).to(device)



    for param in transform.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
        param.volatile = True

    
    names = sorted(glob.glob(data))
```

And I get the error below

```
raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be enough to add this at the beginning of your code(the line telling PyTorch to use the CPU instead):

```
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

Then, you need to make a global replacement (you will probably have a chance to perform it ***automatically*** in all project's code with the help of your IDE) of `.cuda()` to `.to(device)`

In case the error continues, try setting the value of the variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` in the shell manually:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
```

**In case it is impossible to perform mass method substitution in tangled code, or if you intend to work with models in the future:**

Consider using a ***remote machine with a GPU***. This is usually what Mac users do, in my experience. You can use Google Colab or other similar services if your model is not very large.

Wish you luck :)

Comment: The first part is incorrect, the OP wants to use the CPU, not a cuda device.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks, I corrected to CPU